# Excel & SQL: How to convert string to double in Select statement

Tags: sql, vba, vbscript, ado

I have a sheet in Excel. One column in it ("ID") contains strings with values: 1.01, 1.02, 1.03, 2.01, 3.01, 3.04 etc.

I want to get all rows in that sheet, where "ID" is >= some value using SQL statement and ADO 
connection (from VBScript code). 
So, I have two questions:

1) Can I convert ID's values to double in SQL? So, then I can compare  values as floating point numbers and apply < and > conditions. 
2) Can I use in select statement Macro from Excel workbook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: if I cast column to Integer, I'll have the same effect, so, I used CInt function:

```
Select  *  from ["&strSheetName&"$]   where CInt(TestCaseId)  >= " & abs (strRow)
```

Comment: Bear in mind that `CInt` is "cast to `SMALLINT`" (2 bytes, Int16, etc). If you want "cast to `INTEGER`" (4 bytes, Int32, etc) then you need the `CLng` function. Yes, its counterintuitive that `CInt` doesn't map to SQL `INTEGER` but `CInt` is "borrowed" from VBA for which `Integer` means Int16 (2 bytes) :(

Answer (score 4):

The `CAST` to `FLOAT` function is `CDbl()` e.g.

```
SELECT CDbl(ID) AS ID_float 
  FROM [Sheet$];
```

Note `DOUBLE` is a synonym for `FLOAT`, hence the contraction `C`ast to `D`ou`bl`e

Answer (score 0):

try

```
WHERE CONVERT (ID, FLOAT) >= value
```

Comment: it doesn't work, error: "[Microsoft][ODBC Excel Driver] Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Cast(TestCaseId as Float)> 20.01'."

SQL Statement: Select  *  from [Main$]   where Cast(TestCaseId as Float)> 20.01

Comment: Maybe the query is sensitive to the fact that you don't have a space before your greater than sign?

Comment: I don't think ODBC recognises CAST try using convert. See edited answer.

Comment: with Convert I getting "[Microsoft][ODBC Excel Driver] Undefined function 'CONVERT' in expression."